# Bootstrap Popover: Hover/Click and Close on Outside Click, but Revert to Hover Mode

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the snippet below, I have a Bootstrap Popover which supports both Hover & Click modes. On Click, the window stays open and should close either on (1) self-click (link again), or (2) any outside click.

PROBLEM: After an outside click, the popover goes to the "**currently open**" mode. This means that if you hover over it again, the window is stuck and won't disappear. What should happen is, after an outside click, you revert to the original Hover-and-Disappear mode when you hover over it again. The same behavior is expected here as when hovering after an inside-close-click, which is the original state. Am I forgetting something?

```js
$('#linkPopover').popover({
  trigger: 'hover click', 
  content: 'This is my content', 
  title: 'TITLE'
});

// -----------------
// Just with the above (and no other code), the Hover and Click-Toggle 
// works within the SAME Popover window,
// but now I need to also remove the visible Popover on ANY CLICK OUTSIDE.

// However, although the below works, *after* clicking outside the Popover is in the CLICKED 
// mode i.e. it doesn't hover anymore

$('body').on('click', function(e) {
     $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
         if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
              // From outside click with the popover open, need to hide
             $(this).popover('hide');
         }      
     });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a id="linkPopover" data-toggle="popover">POPOVER</a>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
End of body
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code might help you. I changed your conditional statements to check if the user is clicking outside of the popover trigger &&  if the popover is visible, then trigger the `click` event of the popover trigger.
 I thought of doing this because the `click` event is the event that occurs when you click the trigger itself.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#linkPopover').popover({
  trigger: 'hover click',
  content: 'This is my content', 
  title: 'TITLE'
});

$('body').on('click', function(e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        if(!$(this).is(e.target) && ($("#linkPopover").next('div.popover:visible').length)){
        $("#linkPopover").trigger('click');
    }
    });
});

});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a id="linkPopover" data-toggle="popover">POPOVER</a>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
End of body
</body>
```

Comment: There is one problem with this solution, though. Because you do `trigger('click')` that creates an infinite loop in case there are multiple popovers and we catch all `body.click`'s. At least when we were doing `hide` on the popover it wasn't propagating back up to `body.click`. But now, imagine there are multiple links. I click and pin the 1st one, then click and pin the 2nd one. This creates an infinite loop. In reality the 2nd should close the 1st one.

Comment: good find sir gene, see my new answer that I posted just now. hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I actually solved the infinite-loop in eminememinem's original answer (due to `trigger('click')`) by introducing a custom flag parameter in the `body.click`. You can do that as

```
     $('body').on('click', function (e, manualClickTriggered) {
```

We set the flag in the special case of our own re-triggering. If so we ignore the regular logic.

Full snippet:

```js
$('[id*="linkPopover"]').popover({
  trigger: 'hover click', 
  content: 'This is my content', 
  title: 'TITLE'
});

// Close any visible popover if clicked outside 
// The "manualClickTriggered" flag indicates that we initiated the special Click event ourselves in order to turn off the popover, in which case skip the regular logic.
$('body').on('click', function (e, manualClickTriggered) {
  var linkId = null;
  if (e.target.id.indexOf("linkPopover") != -1) {
    linkId = e.target.id;
  }
  
  if (manualClickTriggered != true) {
    if (e.target.id.indexOf("linkPopover") == -1) {  // Not coming from any Popover Link (outside click) 
      $('a[id^="linkPopover"][data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {      
        if( !$(this).is(e.target) && ($(this).next('div.popover:visible').length )) {
          $(this).trigger('click', true);
        }
      });
    }
    else // Coming from some Popover link
    {
        $('a[id^="linkPopover"][data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
          if ($(this).attr('id') != linkId && $(this).next('div.popover:visible').length) {
            $(this).trigger('click', true);
          }
        });
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a id="linkPopover1" data-toggle="popover">POPOVER 1</a><br/>
<a id="linkPopover2" data-toggle="popover">POPOVER 2</a><br/>
<a id="linkPopover3" data-toggle="popover">POPOVER 3</a><br/>
<a id="linkPopover4" data-toggle="popover">POPOVER 4</a><br/>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
End of body
```

Answer (score 1):

My first answer produces the `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error due to an infinite loop when there are more than 1 popover (see my first answer and comments).
To solve this: I use `.off` on the body click handler whenever the system is about to execute the `trigger('click')`. After that I reinitialize the body click handler. See sample below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

function initializeClick(){
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        if(!$(this).is(e.target) && ($(this).next('div.popover:visible').length)){
        $('body').off('click');
        $(this).trigger('click');
        initializeClick();
        }
    });
});
}

$('#linkPopover').popover({
  trigger: 'hover click',
  content: 'This is my content', 
  title: 'TITLE'
});

$('#linkPopover2').popover({
  trigger: 'hover click',
  content: 'This is my content', 
  title: 'TITLE'
});

$('body').on('click', function(e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        if(!$(this).is(e.target) && ($(this).next('div.popover:visible').length)){
        $('body').off('click');
        $(this).trigger('click');
        initializeClick();
        }
    });
});

});
```

```html
 <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <a id="linkPopover" class="btn btn-light" data-toggle="popover">POPOVER</a>
<a id="linkPopover2" class="btn btn-light" data-toggle="popover">POPOVER2</a>

    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    End of body
    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks,  upvoted, I also posted my own solution where I use a custom flag parameter in `body.click` that I defined which ignores the main logic if we call click with that param.